# Javascript file is being included but console.log wont work

Tags: javascript

So I THINK I have configured my javascript right in that i want to inlude two files. leaflet.js and mappingsource.js and currently on the page source there exists this:

```
<script type="application/json" data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json">{"path":{"baseUrl":"\/web\/","scriptPath":null,"pathPrefix":"","currentPath":"hello\/world","currentPathIsAdmin":false,"isFront":false,"currentLanguage":"en"},"pluralDelimiter":"\u0003","suppressDeprecationErrors":true,"ajaxPageState":{"libraries":"bartik\/global-styling,big_pipe\/big_pipe,classy\/base,classy\/messages,contextual\/drupal.contextual-links,contextual\/drupal.contextual-toolbar,core\/drupal.active-link,core\/html5shiv,core\/normalize,helloworld\/leaflet,helloworld\/mappingsource,quickedit\/quickedit,shortcut\/drupal.shortcut,system\/base,toolbar\/toolbar,toolbar\/toolbar.escapeAdmin,tour\/tour,user\/drupal.user.icons","theme":"bartik","theme_token":null},"ajaxTrustedUrl":{"\/web\/search\/node":true},"bigPipePlaceholderIds":{"callback=Drupal%5CCore%5CRender%5CElement%5CStatusMessages%3A%3ArenderMessages\u0026args%5B0%5D\u0026token=_HAdUpwWmet0TOTe2PSiJuMntExoshbm1kh2wQzzzAA":true,"callback=user.toolbar_link_builder%3ArenderToolbarLinks\u0026\u0026token=xssKdKFVFD7N0FUPPcC1C7LrqMHpQFVzUhrI4cOeEgs":true,"callback=user.toolbar_link_builder%3ArenderDisplayName\u0026\u0026token=-MH2NzEnTzbzMk0ZGfGgoiw7G3j_-Q1ILWBRVhIOKLI":true,"callback=shortcut.lazy_builders%3AlazyLinks\u0026\u0026token=N1997Wch59v-LxHku3-dD44wjkSNmhegNzlZ8jS0L5I":true},"toolbar":{"breakpoints":{"toolbar.narrow":"only screen and (min-width: 16.5em)","toolbar.standard":"only screen and (min-width: 38.125em)","toolbar.wide":"only screen and (min-width: 61em)"},"subtreesHash":"fFW4IHdcFxAYeqwFjFGFpjKbwADtToCo9LEGFmDLWwY"},"user":{"uid":"1","permissionsHash":"3e05456fe0e0014e93091ef2c6ad9fbbe0e5c07d9303f114c638bbc071d789d2"}}</script>
```

Whih both have settings? for the files that i want however the file mapping source looks like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});

window.onload = "test()";

function test() {
    console.log('123');
}
console.log('test');
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [51.505, -0.09],
    zoom: 13
});
```

Which should be console logging SOMETHING surely? Is there something I'm missing?

Additional files look like this

helloworld.libraries.yml

```
helloworld:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/leaflet.js: {}
    js/mappingsource.js: {}
```

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains helloworld.module.
 */

helloworld.module
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_help().
 */
function helloworld_help($route_name, RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
  switch ($route_name) {
    // Main module help for the helloworld module.
    case 'help.page.helloworld':
      $output = '';
      $output .= '<h3>' . t('About') . '</h3>';
      $output .= '<p>' . t('Hello World example module') . '</p>';
      return $output;

    default:
  }
}

function helloworld_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {

  // Unconditionally attach an asset to the page.
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'helloworld/leaflet';
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'helloworld/mappingsource';

}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function helloworld_theme() {
  return [
    'helloworld' => [
      'render element' => 'children',
    ],
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach complete libraries, not single library files. Your module has the name `helloworld`, this is the first part before the slash. In your libraries.yml you have defined the top key `helloworld`, this is the library name and the second part after the slash:

```
$attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'helloworld/helloworld';
```

This line will attach all JS and all CSS listed under that specific library.

Sidenote: Try to use [Drupal.behaviors](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview) instead of `$(document).ready`, this is the Drupal-way to do stuff like this. Otherwise you might run into problems with Ajax-calls or lazy-rendered blocks rendered with BigPipe module.

Comment: Excellent thank you! Now helloworld/helloworld is in that drupal setting json path but im still not getting the behaviour I want - I will use drupal behaviours and comment back!

Comment: Thanks so much buddy i just got it working based on this